# How does homebrew sets environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, osx-mavericks, homebrew

I am installing Formula using homebrew on OS X 10.9. After installing Maven using homebrew i could not find where is M2_HOME being set. Though if i run "mvn --v" it works but i still can not find M2_HOME.

How does homebrew manages environment variable.

Comment: Probably in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/local/bin/mvn` is a shell script that does some advanced guessing about where the Maven files are installed and sets `M2_HOME` before executing Java.